# Best way to include a user's premium status in database

Tags: android, ios

I have an app with some paid users. So far, I've only depended on the IAP system to verify their paid status, but I'd like to also store that information for myself.

Now, the most straight forward way of doing this that I can think of is to add a field in the user's data structure like:

```json
{
    'uid': 'asdf678sdf',
    'username' : 'coder',
    'isPaidUser' : true,
}
```

I want to know if this is a safe way, or if it has some risks or problems? If there is a better way, could you please share it with me?

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you are safe storing a `Boolean` stating the user is in a specific state, i.e. they paid.

I'm assuming the database is on the device.
In `Android` databases are typically in protected directories so only the owning application can access it.
I can't speak to `ios` but I know its generally more restrictive anyways.

There are pitfalls with using local storage as your data can become stale.
Is this a subscription? If so are you making sure `isPaidUser` is regularly updated?
In short is there any reason `isPaidUser` could be wrong?

Comment: Hey avalerio, thanks for sharing your insight.

Nah it's not a subscription, but i'll still check it regularly. i'll check it against my db every time the user has an internet connection (which I hope is very often!), making sure the user's premium status is in sync with my db. Also will make sure my db is in sync with Apple/Google/etc's IAP history, every once in a while. This will be guarding against very rare cases, as it can only go wrong if I update the `isPaid` status wrongly, or a malicious user messes with my db. It isn't too expensive to do it say monthly, so I think it's worthwhile

Answer (score 1):

Crafty users could potentially mess with the app's local data and flip that flag to "paid" without actually coughing up any dough. Or, if the data isn't locked down tight, someone could intercept it and give themselves free access to all the good stuff.

Storing payment info can be a legal minefield, thanks to things like GDPR and CCPA. You'll need to get users' permission and keep everything super secure, or risk a major headache.

If you have information stored in multiple places (like your app and a server), it can get tricky to keep everything in sync. If things get out of whack, you might end up giving away paid features for free, or worse, locking out paying users!

Comment: `Storing payment info can be a legal minefield` in this case i don't think OP is planning on storing any payment info

Comment: Yeah, I only mean to store a boolean or a paid date or sth like that, so nothing directly related to any sensitive information. The worst case scenario (so the boolean = !truth haha) would just be, like you said, a user getting access to good stuffs for free (which isn't deadly), or a paid user losing access to the good stuff, in which case, i'll get some complaints :P But I intend to check the paid status regularly to minimise such problems.

Thank you for sharing your insight anyway. Really appreciate it <3